# Calling ShowViewModel on activity, does not show Child fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment, mvvmcross

Following the MvvmCross sample [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples)

I am trying to show an activity, that contains a fragment. When I call ShowViewModel on the Activity, I see the activity, without the contained fragment.

If I call ShowViewModel on the Fragment, the Activity AND the Fragment are created.

Does this mean, in order to show a fragment I need to call ShowViewModel on the fragment and not on the parent activity? surly I should be able to call ShowViewModel on the activity and have that create the fragment.

Sorry if i'm missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: @Martijn00 can answer this, please :)

Comment: Yes you need to call ShowViewModel to the fragment. The attribute on the fragment will resolve the host Activity and automatically show it.

Comment: @Martijn00 ok, but how do i share that logic with iOS. for example. I have a profile activity that contains a fragment with a list. On iOS, we ShowProfileViewModel. and we init the ListViewModel from the ProfileViewModel. This works fine. But to use the same logic in my core project for Android, that's not going to work. on Android I need to ShowListViewModel  first which will create the ProfileViewModel.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus on how to share code using that. You could also create your own presenter.

Comment: @Martijn00 Thank you